# How to keep my music from starting over when user goes to new page

Tags: html, audio, handlebars.js

I'm working on a simple dating sim game, and I want the background music to not only loop but not start over when the user goes to a new page.

I put the following code in my main.handlebars hoping it would just keep playing no matter what but it keeps reloading whenever I go to a new page.

```
<audio autoplay loop>
<source src="img/zombiemusic.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
</audio>
```

Is there a different way of doing what I want or is it not possible?

Comment: Are your pages all separate index files?

Comment: Yes and no? I'm new to handlebars. I have the mainhandlebar calling in divs from other handlebar pages